# How likely is it that a random plane through the origin will intersect positive space?

Tags: probability, geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-probability

In an n-dimensional hyperspace, how likely is it that a randomly chosen plane passing through the origin will intersect "all-positive co-ordinate space"?

(By "all-positive co-ordinate space" I mean the space where all cartesian coordinates are positive. For instance, in a 2-D space, this would be the upper right quadrant. In 3-D space, this would be the region where x>0 and y>0 and z>0.)

Equivalent question: in n-D space, given a randomly chosen vector, how likely is it that a perpendicular vector exists with all positive cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Randomly chosen in what sense?

Comment: Uniform distribution randomness. One could randomly choose a unit vector, from which one can construct a perpendicular plane through the origin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hyperplane will intersect "all positive space" iff its normal vector is neither in "all positive space" nor in "all negative space". This gives a probability of $1-2^{1-n}$.

Comment: I think you want $1-2^{1-n}$.

Comment: This solution seems to make intuitive sense, but how can one prove/justify it?

Comment: @xenocyon If there are two coordinates in the normal vector that has opposite signs, then it is not difficult to exploit that to produce a vector in the hyperplane with all coordinates positive. On the other hand, if the normal vector has all coordinates positive (resp. negative), then no vector in all positive space can be orthogonal to it, since the dot product must evaluate to something positive (resp. negative), and cannot be $0$.